# How to send loop index to another class?

Tags: java, android, loops

I will send value of loop index (variable **i**) to another class. I decided to use *putExtra* but to do this variable **i** have to be a "final".As you know that's impossible because this variable change value for each of the loop.

Here my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i<=20; i++) {
    btn[i].getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF00FF00,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

    btn[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {   
            Intent intent = new Intent(newgame.this, game.class);
            intent.putExtra(game.KEY_MISSION, i);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
     });
}
```

If you have any ideas or solutions I would be very grateful for your reply.
(Sorry for my english)

Answer (score 4):

You can do this

```
for (int i = 0; i<=20; i++) {

       final int j = i;

         btn[i].getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF00FF00,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

         btn[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {  

                Intent intent = new Intent(newgame.this, game.class);
                intent.putExtra(game.KEY_MISSION, j);
                startActivity(intent);

                 }
             });

     }
```

Comment: Omg, <facepalm> Sorry for that question.. too many beers today..
Anyway thanks for help, that's works..

Answer (score 0):

Create an inner class that takes 'i' as a parameter to the constructor.  This is an example of when NOT to use an anonymous inner class, since you are creating multiple instances with different information.

Comment: An anonymous inner class is fine here - you just need an extra variable in the loop.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - You can, I just don't think you should.  IMHO it is more clear to use a named class as the alternative seems a bit of a hack, although I admit the named class would be a little more code.